# How to delete selected row of jTable in database using Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate

This is how i got items into the `jTable`:

```
    public void fillKategorija(){
        Session sesija = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        tx = sesija.beginTransaction();
        List kategorije = sesija.createQuery("from Kategorija").list();
        tx.commit();
        DefaultTableModel tablemodel = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        for(Iterator iterator = kategorije.iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
            Kategorija kat = (Kategorija)iterator.next();
            tablemodel.addRow(new Object[]{
            kat.getId(),kat.getNaziv(),kat.getOpis()
            });
        }
}
```

and this is how i tried to delete selected row from the database:

```
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int red = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel(); 
        int id = Integer.parseInt(dtm.getValueAt(red, 0).toString());
        Session sesija = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        tx = sesija.beginTransaction();
        Kategorija kat = new Kategorija();
        kat.setId(id);
        sesija.delete(kat);
        tx.commit();
    }
```

and I get this error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [model.Kategorija#20]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead of the code

```
Kategorija kat = new Kategorija();
kat.setId(id);
sesija.delete(kat);
```

try to use retrieving the object rather than creating new Kategorija

```
Kategorija kat = sesija.get(Kategorija.class, id)
sesija.delete(kat);
```